# How to control 220V RGB Led Strip with Arduino/ESP32

Tags: arduino-mega, esp32, rgb-led

I need to control 220V RGB Led strip with Arduino/ESP32-wroom over internet.
Single color led is easy (just with a relay), 12V RGB can be done with PWM and maybe external power source. But how can I control 220V RGB via MCU?
I couldn't find any answer yet.

Comment: there is no such thing as 220 V AC LED (yet). it is a 12 V LED and an AC/DC power supply. what controls does it have?

Comment: In Australia, we have LED light bulbs that screw into the 240V light socket. Sure there is circuitry in the bulb to convert the incoming power to suitable ranges for the LED's to operate, but the light bulb is LED based and does require 240V AC. I'm surprised these are not available elsewhere. https://www.beaconlighting.com.au/lighting/globes-bulbs-lights/led-globes-lights

Comment: @GMc, yes the LED bulb has AC/DC adapter insight. a dimmable version senses the AC voltage and dims the DC side with PWM. a not dimmable version would not dim with triac. and a RGB version needs some additional controls, usually wireless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at a relay or a [triac](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIAC).

Also, you can not simply "use PWM to control a 12V circuit from your MCU" which is most likely running at 5V. You need to use a component such as a MOSFET. The MCU controls the MOSFET via the Gate. The MOSFET switches the 12 V circuit off or on based upon the signal at the gate.

Alternatively, like the AC solution, you can use a Relay to control the 12V circuit.

Comment: @alper, WARNING! DANGER! this accepted answer is wrong and can destroy your equipment and harm you! Controlling a switching power supply of the AC/DC adapter for the LED strip will destroy the triac and/or the AC/DC adapter.

Comment: @juraj, can you elaborate?  From https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/power/triac.html (and other similar sites) "*This makes the triac ideal to control a lamp or AC motor load with a very basic triac switching circuit*". Here is a shield designed to do it  https://www.circuitar.com/nanoshields/modules/triac/. And yes, I absolutely agree the voltages the OP is asking about are dangerous and if there is any uncertainty he/she shouldn't go anywhere near it.

Comment: @Alper, there are some excellent safety warnings on the site https://www.circuitar.com/nanoshields/modules/triac/ Juraj is 100% correct about the dangers of playing with mains voltages. I encourage you in the strongest possible terms to read the [safety information](https://www.circuitar.com/nanoshields/modules/triac/)

Comment: a switching power supply turns the AC line on and off fast. capacitor does the smoothing of the output. triac dimmer turns the AC line on and off fast too. imagine the resulting effect.

Comment: https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2011/jul/dimming-leds-with-traditional-triac-dimmers

Comment: That is good advice, thanks for including it. I wonder if OP wants to dim or just switch off and on. The OP was pretty vague in general, but the "question" has served to generate some useful contributions (IMHO). Although I would still question as to whether my answer is "wrong" as the digikey article explains how Triacs can be correctly used to Dim an LED.